# explode a string like in SQL by preg_match

Tags: php, preg-match

I want to explode a string like in SQL

this is my code:

```
<?php

$subject = 'select onlineid from onlinelist where online_user_name=6565 order by htrdh limit 1';

preg_match('/^(select|SELECT) (?P<select>(.+)) (from|FROM) (?P<from>(.+)) ((where|WHERE) (?P<where>(.+))) ((order by|ORDER BY) (?P<order>(.+)))? ((limit|LIMIT) (?P<limit>(.+)))?$/', $subject, $matches);

echo @$matches["select"]."<br>".@$matches["from"]."<br>".@$matches["where"]."<br>".@$matches["order"]."<br>".@$matches["limit"];
```

outPut will be :

```
onlineid
onlinelist
online_user_name=6565
htrdh
1
```

workes well...
But if I remove `order by` or `limit` it does not work.

it must if `where`, `order by` or `limit` exists in `$subject` put value

Comment: preg_match('/^(select|SELECT) (?P<select>(.+)) (from|FROM) (?P<from>(.+)) ((where|WHERE) (?P<where>(.+))) ((order by|ORDER BY) (?P<order>(.+)))? ((limit|LIMIT)\s+(?P<limit>(.+)))?$/', $subject, $matches);

Comment: Instead of having `select|SELECT` and all those things you could just use `strtolower` or instead use the `i` modifier as the query could also look like `Select` and on that case your regex wont work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `?` did not include the spaces.

Incorrect: `... (ORDER BY ...)? (LIMIT ...)?`

Correct: `...( ORDER BY ...)?( LIMIT ...)?`

https://www.regex101.com/r/mE8qK5/1

I also recommend that you add `?` to the `.+` subpatterns so that it won't match greedily (lazy)

[What do lazy and greedy mean in the context of regular expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301285/what-do-lazy-and-greedy-mean-in-the-context-of-regular-expressions)

Answer (score 1):

Regex is tricky and you should always be careful of using it unless you know every aspect of it.
I would also suggest using /i for case insensitive

https://www.regex101.com/r/hM9aC7/1

```
/^select\s+(?<columns>.*?)\s+from\s+(.*?)?((where\s+(?<where>.*?))?(order by\s+(?<order>.*?))?(limit\s+(?<limit>(.*?)))?);/i
```